# module not found matplotlib.finance

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, finance

I have installed the latest version of Anaconda recently. When I am trying to import matplotlib.finance, I have a `module does not exist` error in spyder.

> matplotlib and mpl-finance are installed already.

What should I do to resolve the issue?

I have the following problem with the following code in python 3.7
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc

```
   File "<ipython-input-1-7ea83a59eaf3>", line 1, in <module>
     from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.finance'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib.finance` does not exist (anymore).

If you have installed mpl-finance, you need to import it as `mpl_finance`, e.g.

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a now a new version of this module.  Try this: https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/